# Should I display "no alarms" info in a summary view?

Tags: gui-design

There is certain summary overview in the system that my team is developing. In this summary overview one section is dedicated to displaying active alarms. My team and I had a discussion how to handle the situation when there are no active alarms.

Should we display description "No active alarms" or such or should the alarm area remain empty?

Things of note that alarm section is in upper middle part of the view and it takes about of quarter of width of screen and is about 150px tall. The alarms are communicated using alarm cards with only color, icon and number.

EDIT: I hesitated with mocks since our app is terribly work-in-progress, but here they are:
[image: no alarms mock]
[image: mock with some alarms]

Comment: Hi @RockyMM can you please upload the screenshot or give example of layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user sees an empty area where there is supposed to be a list of elements (whether it is one or more) he could think:

- there are no items
- there might be items but they are not showing up: still not loaded, some error, etc.

If the user sees a "no items" message the only thing he can think is:

- there are no items

So, in my opinion, it is a good idea to reinforce the state of the element, even if it might sound unnecessary, to **prevent make the user think**.

Comment: Or they might not realise that anything can be there at all, and remain unaware of a whole feature of your product!

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer since you've made a point of "preventing user to think". Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm sections is less important when there is no alarm. So when you have no alarms then you can just display disable section having placeholder like "No Active Alarm."

Another option is to hide just alarm portion when it is empty. So as per user experience it won't occupy unnecessary space and remaining information would be represented properly.You can set one small icon of alarm at the top right section in the header with visibility "disable". So it's easy for anyone to understand that there is no active alarm right now.

At last once again would like to suggest you that please don' keep the alarms section as it is if there is no alarms.Because it's of no use.